# Trigger CI-job when files outside a directory were done

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

My project contains a folder with UI related code. For my tests I have API tests and UI tests I want to trigger jobs with the specific scenarios, If changes in UI directory run UI test, this can be done with only tag,

```
only:
    changes:
      - directory/UI/**/*
```

, and then I want to run API test if changes to API. problem is my project has about 20 directory and only one contains UI for API is there a way to do it without only,

```
only:
        changes:
          - directory1/project/**/*
          - directory2/project/**/*
          - directory3/project/**/*
          - directory5/project/**/*
          - directory6/project/**/*
          - directory7/project/**/*
          - directory8/project/**/*
```

I can use except but this will only work for UI only changes and API only changes but not for when both API and UI changes are being made. is there a way to find a work around numerating all directories? thinking something like only changes outside Directory/UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one job for UI changes that has

```yaml
only:
  changes:
    - directory/UI/*
```

and another job for API changes like:

```yaml
only:
  changes:
    - directory/API/*
    - ...
```

then if you push changes to both the UI and API, both jobs will run in the pipeline.

Here's a full `.gitlab-ci.yml` example (this is just a dumb example since I don't know what your pipeline does):

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

Build The App:
  stage: build
  script:
    - # run some build steps like `npm ci`, `npm run build`, generating config files, etc.

Test UI Changes:
  stage: test
  only:
    changes:
      - /path/to/UI
  script:
    - # test the UI

Test API Changes:
  stage: test
  only:
    changes:
      - /path/to/API
  script:
    - # test the API

Deploy:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
    - # deploy the whole app
```

In this example, anything build steps that need to happen for either the API or UI happen in the `build` stage, whether in one job or multiple - that's up to you. The Test stage has two jobs since we test the UI and API separately, but only need to run the tests if there are changes to the UI or API. If we push up changes only to the UI, only that job will run, and the same with the API job. However, if we make changes to both, then both jobs will run in this stage.

Finally, we deploy the app when the tests succeed.